# I can't install lableImg Annotation tool in M1 Mac

Tags: apple-m1, labelimg

While installing LabelImg in M1 Mac using below command

*pip install pyqt5 lxml*

This is the error I got

ERROR: pyqt5 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'

How to install lableImg annotation tool in M1 Mac?

Answer (score 6):

I got it to work by using the following commands

```
brew install pyqt@5
pip install labelimg
```

And that's it, it just works
You just need to type `labelimg` in the Terminal and the app will start running

I don't know why they don't tell you this in the installation guide

Answer (score 3):

Alrighty!

On MacOS Monterey, none of the other solutions posted here solved this problem for me. However, I managed to easily solve the issue, without a virtual environment or too much fiddling about like so:

Firstly, you have to download all labelImg packages from this link:

https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg#macos

(You can download it as a .zip file or clone it)

Unzip and then **in your terminal cd into whatever directory you downloaded the above files to.**

Then run the following commands in order:

```
    pyrcc5 -o libs/resources.py resources.qrc
```

Then,

```
    pip3 install lxml
```

Finally,

```
   python3 labelImg.py
```

It should run without an issue now.

Answer (score 2):

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/labelimg

Install anaconda on m1 mac first

https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution

Make sure python and pip is installed using following commands

```
python --version 
pip --version
conda --version
```

open terminal

```
conda install -c conda-forge labelimg
labelImg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go one of two ways:

**Using brew:**

You can use [homebrew to install the dependencies](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg#macos) - like `qt` and `libxml2`. This will let your package manager handle everything and generally should solve the problem with the . Then you can run

```
    python3 labelimg.py
```

**Using Virtual Environments:**

This is the more recommended way to go about in such cases. You can use `conda`, `pipenv` or `venv` to create a virtual environment which is isolated from your system python installation. Then you can try to install it as explained in the [README.rst](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg#readme) in the root of the repository:

```
brew install python3
pip3 install pipenv
pipenv run pip install pyqt5==5.12.1 lxml
pipenv run make qt5py3
pipenv run python3 labelImg.py
[Optional] rm -rf build dist; python setup.py py2app -A;mv "dist/labelImg.app" /Applications
```

You can try the two methods and and get back with the errors if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

This is my note.

I just succeed on my Mac M1 Chip

CHECK THIS OUT!

### [image: LabelImg]

## Installation of labelimg on mac m1 chip

[my first reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901162/how-can-i-run-pyqt5-on-my-mac-with-m1chip)

[my second reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901162/how-can-i-run-pyqt5-on-my-mac-with-m1chip)

First, you must use terminal with rosetta version

Then, you already have python3

Then...

[Done]

```
# check where python3 is
$ where python3

# create env
$ /usr/bin/python3 -m venv env

# check env is
$ where env

# activate env list
$ source env/bin/activate 

# updated to the newest
$ pip install --upgrade pip

# installation of PyQt5
$ pip install PyQt5

# start to run labelImg.py
$ cd Documents/repos/labelImg
$ pip3 install pyqt5 lxml
$ make qt5py3

# [run ok!!]
$ python3 labelImg.py
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using Conda

1. Create a virtual environment in conda and activate it

```
conda create -n venv
conda activate venv
```

2. Install pyqt using conda

```
conda install pyqt
```

3. Install lxml using pip

```
pip install lxml
```

4. Change directory to the downloaded/cloned labelImg folder

```
cd path/to/labelImg/folder/
```

5. Make qt5py3

```
make qt5py3
```

6. Run LabelImg

```
python labelImg.py
```

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by AAA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71160236/3329384) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75007464/3329384) got me the closest. I don't have `pipenv` installed but do have a regular venv activated. In full, and even with qt6 installed already:

```
python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip

brew install libxml2
brew install pyqt@5

# check the path with `brew --prefix qt5`
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/qt5/bin:$PATH"

# The following will take a while:
pip3 install pyqt5 --config-settings --confirm-license --verbose

pip3 install labelImg
```

You need the full `confirm-license` command above to [avoid getting stuck later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66546886/pip-install-stuck-on-preparing-wheel-metadata-when-trying-to-install-pyqt5).

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still (as of Jul 2023) trying to run on an arm7 machine:

> pip install labelImg

and still get multiple errors like PyQt5 related, here is what I did:

> 1. Checked my homebrew installation place for x86 and arm7.
>    - Made alias for homebrew in *zsh file* (More reference by [Nigel Davies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65424574/12637995))

```
alias ibrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew'
alias mbrew='arch -arm64e /opt/homebrew/bin/brew'
```

> 2. Used *ibrew* to install python3

```
ibrew install python3
```

> 3. Next was to create virtual environment

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m venv env
```

> 4. Activate the virtual env

```
source env/bin/activate
```

> 5. Then installed PyQt5

```
pip install PyQt5
```

> 6. Head to cloned repository for *labelImg*

```
 cd path/to/labelImg
 pip3 install pyqt5 lxml
 make qt5py3
```

> 7. Run the *labelImg.py*

```
 python labelImg.py
```