# How to install PyQtWebEngine in m1 pro?

Tags: python, pyqt5

how to install  PyQtWebEngine by m1 pro,macos

install error

```
pip install -i  PyQtWebEngine
Looking in indexes: 
Collecting PyQtWebEngine
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/cf/4b/ca01d875eff114ba5221ce9311912fbbc142b7bb4cbc4435e04f4f1f73cb/PyQtWebEngine-5.15.6.tar.gz (48 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/52/qg4pw1dj73j4t7s079kckmz80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6asbq8b/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
        File "/private/var/folders/52/qg4pw1dj73j4t7s079kckmz80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6asbq8b/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/private/var/folders/52/qg4pw1dj73j4t7s079kckmz80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6asbq8b/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 584, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/52/qg4pw1dj73j4t7s079kckmz80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6asbq8b/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/52/qg4pw1dj73j4t7s079kckmz80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6asbq8b/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 236, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/52/qg4pw1dj73j4t7s079kckmz80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6asbq8b/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

i Follow the URL operation to install or can not install normally

https://github.com/emacs-eaf/emacs-application-framework/issues/868

How to install PyQtWebEngine in m1 ? I tried pip3 install PyQtWebEngine.

Comment: See if [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961915/error-while-installing-pytq5-with-pip-preparing-metadata-pyproject-toml-did-n) help?

Comment: not help,pyqt has already install sucess,but PyQtWebEngine install fail

Answer (score 0):

Installing the PyQtWebEngine can be a bit tricky (I know from my own experience), but you could just try installing it with homebrew if you have it.

That would work like this:

`brew install qtwebengine`

Otherwise you could try this:

`pip install --no-cache-dir PyQtWebEngine`

This would help you if you have cache errors.