# PyQt5 tools error Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

when installing pyqt5 tools after installing pyqt5 using pip commad i get this error
i already installed pyqt5 with 'pip install pygt5'

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
DEPRECATION: Loading egg at c:\program files\python312\lib\site-packages\vboxapi-1.0-py3.12.egg is deprecated. pip 24.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation.. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12330
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.9.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting click (from pyqt5-tools)
  Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.9 (from pyqt5-tools)
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.8 MB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyqt5-tools to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.4 (from pyqt5-tools)
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yl4i5kg6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yl4i5kg6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yl4i5kg6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 586, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yi_tz1v2\pyqt5_ed929b1887ec44d3ab4ffb88ed4a6082\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yl4i5kg6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yl4i5kg6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\ihabk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yl4i5kg6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

i saw some solution that suggest downgrading python version to 3.9
any solution for latest python version (3.12)

Comment: Hello, did you happen to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961915/error-while-installing-pytq5-with-pip-preparing-metadata-pyproject-toml-did-n) answer? Does it fit the scenario you might be under?