# pip install pyqt5, it cannot go on

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

```
 Successfully installed PyQt-builder-1.13.0 packaging-21.3 ply-3.11 pyparsing-3.0.9 setuptools-65.3.0 sip-6.6.2 toml-0.10.2
  Cleaning up...
    Removing source in /tmp/pip-install-2gmr_frd/sip
  Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-vuj8lfsc'
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmppi_h1r7x get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpx88x82dh
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-b__1na9b
    Running command /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpwp46ffki prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpxrg1n2t9
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.15.7 (licensed under the GNU General Public License) for Python 3.8.2 on linux.

    Type 'L' to view the license.
    Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
    Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.
```

But I can't type any words, and it stopped there.
It's an aarch64 machine.

Comment: What command did you *exactly* type and with what terminal emulator? Are you sure that you cannot just type "yes" and press enter (even if you don't see the typed text on the screen)?

Comment: pip  install pyqt5 --verbose .  mate-terminal

Comment: i can see the typed text, but it doesn't work when  enter is pressed

Comment: I have the same issue, on OSX. My typed in 'yes' and enter after that is not forwarded to the right process it seems.

Comment: @musicamante I can answer your question. I'm also sure I cannot just type "yes" and press enter. I do see the typed text on the screen. I do see a newline appear after pressing enter. Nothing happens after pressing enter.

Comment: What version of pip and Python are you using? You can use `pip --version` to print this out.

Comment: You can try [this solution ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41673145/19947054) or [similar to that ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664167/19947054)

Comment: I get the OPs same error/stall point when installing pyqt5-tools on a Mac, and tried everything, including installing Qt5 on its own (brew install Qt5). Still can't get past this prompt. Ive never had a problem with installing a package before

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue, due to there being no wheel installation for my platform (Macbook w/ OSX Arm64). When pip does not have a wheel to work from, it attempts to compile from source. By passing a --config-settings argument to pip you can pass an argument to the configure.py which would be used during compilation. Luckily pyqt has an argument to automatically accept the license --confirm-license. However, pip expects the argument in a Key=value form so you need to pass --confirm-license= (i.e. no value) and it will work. It took a while (about 30+ min) but I did finally get pyqt5 installed.

here is the command I used:

```
pip3 install pyqt5 --config-settings --confirm-license= --verbose
```

hope this helps.

Comment: If you get an error about no `config-settings` option update your pip: `pip install -U pip`

Comment: How do you do this if your installation of PyQt5 is done in a `requirements.txt` file? I tried doing: "PyQt5==5.15.4 --config-settings --confirm-license=" but that didn't work, I still see the prompt (which I can't respond to!) about the license.

Comment: @RaleighL. same problem here. It still stucks in the "Type 'yes'" part for me.

Answer (score 3):

Thankyou for the help with the hang during `Preparing wheel metadata … -`
Once I upgraded pip:

```
pip -U install pip
```

And then used that version to allow for the license confirmation

```
~/.local/bin/pip3 install pyqt5 —-config-settings —-confirm-license= —-verbose
```

the installation completed without hanging!! I had mistakenly thought the hang and killed process had to do with the machine not having enough swap space, but this is not the case. Please note that during the period of time when it is waiting for a license confirmation, before the process is killed, memory usage increases. Once I had upped to 25 gig of swap space, while still having the issues, I realized it had nothing to do with that. The process was simply waiting for the license confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Params `--config-settings` and `--confirm-license` are not available on Linux `pip` apparently.

Doing it this way somehow bypassed the problem:

```
pip3 install pyqt5==5.12.0
```

In my experience, installing anything on `pip` seems to turn into a dependency nightmare whereas `apt` has been rock solid for decades. No idea why.

Comment: I found this not to be the case: I was able to run the command from ninjaphysics' answer on Linux and it completed with no problems. Maybe it depends on the pip version? (Also, I don't think the general griping about pip is useful here. I understand that you may have had dependency problems with Python packages, but millions of people do not - it's demonstrably not true in general that "installing anything on pip seems to turn into a dependency nightmare".)

Comment: Have added pedantic clarification that it is an opinion based on personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to use `pip3 install pyqt5 --config-settings --confirm-license= --verbose` It give me the errot is `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError.` It is so bad for me .

Comment: I install it successfully ! I try to use it again ,successfully!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34474316)